# xhprof on WampServer 2.2

Tags: php, wampserver, xhprof

I am trying to get XHProf working on my WampServer.

I have downloaded the dll from: http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-extensions/xhprof/file/details/xhprof-0103-for-php-53-vc9.html and renamed to xhprof.dll in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\ext (Which is the dir listed for extensions in phpinfo())

Php.ini path from phpinfo():
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin\php.ini

Extensions listed in that file:

```
 extension=php_curl.dll
 extension=xhprof.dll
 ;extension=php_dba.dll
 extension=php_mbstring.dll
 ;extension=php_exif.dll
 ;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
 extension=php_gd2.dll
 ;extension=php_gettext.dll
 ;extension=php_gmp.dll
 ;extension=php_intl.dll
 ;extension=php_imap.dll
 ;extension=php_interbase.dll
 ;extension=php_ldap.dll
 ;extension=php_ming.dll
 ;extension=php_mssql.dll
 extension=php_mysql.dll
 extension=php_mysqli.dll
 ;extension=php_oci8.dll
 ;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll 
 ;extension=php_openssl.dll
 ;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
 ;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
 extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
 ;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
 ;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
 ;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
 extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
 ;extension=php_pgsql.dll
 ;extension=php_phar.dll
 ;extension=php_pspell.dll
 ;extension=php_shmop.dll
 ;extension=php_snmp.dll
 ;extension=php_soap.dll
 ;extension=php_sockets.dll
 ;extension=php_sqlite.dll
 ;extension=php_sqlite3.dll
 ;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
 ;extension=php_tidy.dll
 ;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
 ;extension=php_xsl.dll
 ;extension=php_zip.dll
```

But when I restart WampServer and the services associated with it, no XHProf information appears in phpinfo()

I am looking for a way to fix this, or a further way to investigate why this extension isnt loading

Thanks

Comment: Have you got any errors in your PHP/Apache error logs? What version of WampServer are you running, and on what OS?

Comment: Im running WampServer 2.2 on Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: It also seems I do have an error in the apache_error.log: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.9/ext/xhprof.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using WampServer 64-bit, but the xhprof.dll is made for the 32-bit architecture and isn't compatible. Ony my own Windows 7 machine I got this error in the apache_error.log:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/ext/php_xhprof.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/ext/php_xhprof.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

It doesn't seem that there is a 64-bit version at this time, so you are limited to options of what you can do. The first choice is to use the 32-bit version of WampServer (on a development machine I can't see too many drawbacks with this). The second is to sweet-talk the makers at fresh-site to compile/support 64-bit. Good luck!

Comment: Makes sense - id checked everything else matched but forgot about x86 vs 64

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Leonard Challis.  I had a similar error for a few hours.  I needed to use php_ibm_db2.dll. After adding it to the extension folder and the php.ini file.  I started getting the error message.

**Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_ibm_db2.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.**

Some solutions I came across advise to put it in the system32 folder.  That did not help.  I went to several forums and blogs.  All advises failed.  Until I saw you recommendation.  So simple, can't figure out why I did not think of that.  Although the error message is a bit vague.

BTW, for those who are working with a **PHP to DB2 environment the dll files may be obtained here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/db2mc/files/**.

Ensure that you also install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) -  vcredist_x86.exe.

**http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328**

I hope this helps anyone that may have a similar problem in the future.  Thanks to everyone who contributed to this forum.  It was a great help.